# iRobot Create + Hokuyo LIDAR + YAML map + AMCL

Tags: ros, navigation, irobot-create-2-1, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a PGM/YAML map generated from hector SLAM from a Hokuyo LIDAR driven around by an iRobot Create. I was trying to use AMCL for localization and simple 2d nav goals, but it seems to be very problematic for some reason.

The brown pkg provides the /odom and /tf, and I use map_server to publish the /map topic. I ran the hokuyo_node (laser scans published on /scan) and then rosrun amcl amcl.

1. AMCL outputs:

No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1367364115.808416 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.
MessageFilter [target=/odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.amcl.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.

2. The /map subscription in rviz shows:
   No transform from [map] to [/base_link]

If I go through hector_slam, it looks like it's estimating the /odom topic from the laser scan itself, but there's no localization feature. Any suggestions as to what might need to be changed to make AMCL work with the Create's odom/tf on a known map?

Thank you
Sai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61891/irobot-create-+-hokuyo-lidar-+-yaml-map-+-amcl/) by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2013-04-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3961/gav/) on 2013-04-30**:
What tf frame is the laser in? If 'laser', is there something publishing a link between the /base_link and /laser?

If there's nothing publishing it already, try adding a static transform publisher as described here:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher
edit: added link to pub

**Comment by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on 2013-04-30**:
I think it's on /scan. I even tried moving the hokuyo_node to /base_scan and running amcl on base_scan.

**Comment by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on 2013-04-30**:
Thanks, I will try putting a transform between base_link and laser. (rosrun tf view_frames doesn't work for me). Any inputs about the odom?

**Comment by [Gav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3961/gav/) on 2013-04-30**:
Run 'rostopic echo /scan | more', and you'll see the header saying which frame it's in. My one is 'laser'.
You can then specify the relationship saying the height/etc of your laser related to your base.

**Comment by [Gav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3961/gav/) on 2013-04-30**:
e.g.  would indicate the laser is directly above the base link by 0.5m

**Comment by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on 2013-04-30**:
Got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you might need laser_scan_matcher to provide 'fake' odometry for amcl to work.

---

Originally posted by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) with karma: 123 on 2013-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0